# Move/turn object in PyMOL

Tags: python, plugins, pymol

I'm writing a plugin for PyMOL.

I already have some sphere drawn (a compiled graphics object), and now I need to change it's coordinates. What command do I need to use to set new coordinates for my cgo sphere?

When I create an object I use `cmd.load_cgo(data, 'name')` but how to move this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a good tutorial on pymol http://www.liv.ac.uk/~afcalder/apt1.html

as it describes, and what I confirm, there are some commands like `translate` or `rotate` that can modify coordinates of the scene and particular objects when parameter `object` is given